# Swift String to Int Always Returns nil

Tags: swift, string, int

I am trying to convert a String to an Int. Seems simple enough, but for somer reason it is always returning `nil`.

I'm just writing a simple extension to convert dollars to cents:

```
func dollarsToCents() -> Int {
    var temp = self;
    temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
    temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

    if let number = Int(temp) {
        return number*100
    }

    return 0
}
```

I have `temp` set to "$250.89". `number` is always nil. No matter how I approach converting `temp` to an Int it is always nil. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use a `NumberFormatter`, don't parse a currency formatted String manually.

Comment: I updated my question. Not sure how it's working for you and not me.

Comment: @tentmaking Most likely they tested with an integer string and not a decimal string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is, that string `"250.89"` (after removing currency symbol) can't be converted to `Int` because `250.89` isn't integer. So fix your code by converting it to `Double`

```
func dollarsToCents() -> Int {
    var temp = self
    temp.removeAll { "$,".contains($0) }
    //temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "[$,]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    return Int(((Double(temp) ?? 0) * 100).rounded())
}
```

or if your "number" always have two decimal places

```
func dollarsToCents() -> Int {
    var temp = self
    temp.removeAll { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }
    return Int(temp) ?? 0
}
```

---

But I think solution is much easier. Your goal should be saving *price* value as number (`Double`,...). Then you don't have to convert `String` to `Double` and you can just multiply your number. Then when you need to add currency symbol, just convert your value to `String` and add `$` or use `NumberFormatter`

```
let price = 250.89
let formattedPrice = "$\(price)" // $250.89
```

---

```
let price = 250.89
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
let formattedPrice = formatter.string(from: price as NSNumber)! // $250.89
```

Comment: `NumberFormatter` is the way to go. In addition to being easier, it is more flexible, being able to be adjusted if you need to account for other locales (for example, certain European countries where the period and comma are reversed in decimal representations—i.e. 123.456,78 instead of 123,456.78).

Comment: @CharlesSrstka yes, that's right! But since he'd mentioned dollars in his question, I wanted to be sure that this always returns `$`

Comment: You can adjust the `currencySymbol` property on `NumberFormatter`. Additionally, this leaves the path open to easily supporting other currencies in the future.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka that's true. Thank you! :) I edited my answer.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka It's not only about the currency symbol, it's also about the position. English is one of the few languages that display currency symbol before the amount. In my language this would be formatted as `"250,89 USD"`. And there could be also negative amounts where formatting is even trickier. We don't know the actual use case though.

Comment: @Sulthan That's a good point. Instead of `currencySymbol`, it's probably best to do `formatter.currencyCode = "USD"`, which will cause `NumberFormatter` to do the right thing (in the US, this results in `$` getting put in front of the number).

Comment: @RobertDresler Note that you don't have to remove any character from the string, you can also use NumberFormatter to parse it. `let price = "$250.89"`
`let formatter = NumberFormatter()`
`formatter.numberStyle = .currency`
`let number = formatter.number(from: price)! // 250.89`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, to be clear, `NumberFormatter` should be used any time currency strings need to be converted to numbers, or vice versa. However, I also agree with the answerer that it's better to store the price as a `Double` rather than a `String` in the first place, in which case converting a `String` to a `Double` becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @LeoDabus I think in his case when he needs to remove `,` is better to leave it as it is.

Comment: @RobertDresler it would be much easier to remove all non digits and use Int initialiser `func dollarsToCents() -> Int {` 
        `var temp = self` 
        `temp.removeAll { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }` 
        `return Int(temp) ?? 0`
    }`

Comment: @LeoDabus oh, I see, it just removes `.` too so you don't have to multiply it then

Comment: And you don't need to replace the character with an empty string since they've added `removeAll` mutating method on `RangeReplaceableCollection` so you can replace `temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")` with `temp.removeAll { $0 == "$"}`

Comment: if you want multiple characters `removeAll { "$,".contains($0) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus I edited my answer according to your advices. Thanks lot Leo! :-)

Comment: @LeoDabus I actually prefer `temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "[$,]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: @Sulthan Readability wise I prefer `removeAll`. Note that `replacingOccurrences` it is not mutating and there e is no `replaceOccurrences` mutating method. What we need to know is when using thenm with a huge string which one is faster.

Comment: @RobertDresler if you want to add the regex also to replace all non digits `"\\D"`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this for the bizarre edge-case that I just encountered - be sure there aren't any whitespaces either trailing or leading in your string when converting to `Int` from `String`.

Eg.

```
for date in next_thirty_days {
    let date_buffer: String = date.description[8...9]
    date_list.append(Int(date_buffer)!)
}
```

This will fail if the value for `date_buffer` has a leading or trailing white-space.

Another edge-case is that there's a leading `0` in the `string variable`, eg. `07`.

Hope it helps :)